# How to separate an array into multiple lines with sed

Tags: shell, sed

I have a *txt* data like this:

```
A B [C,D,E] [F,G]
```

Want to output results as:

```
A B C F \n
A B C G \n
A B D F \n
A B D G \n
A B E F \n
A B E G \n
```

How can I use `sed` command to do this?

Comment: Show your effort (code)...? And why `sed` and not, e.g., Python?

Comment: Doing this in *pure* `sed` would be difficult.  Pity SE Code Golf doesn't like single language questions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of an existing question, but I could not quickly find anything better than the Python answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789937/iterate-permutation-per-row-per-item

Comment: @agc There are some exception, e.g., Game of Life.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836584/bash-all-combinations-of-lines

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `sed` or `awk` to *"massage"* your strings into this form:

```
"A B" ::: C D E ::: F G
```

You can get **GNU Parallel** to make the permutations for you:

```
parallel -k echo ::: "A B" ::: C D E ::: F G
```

**Output**

```
A B C F
A B C G
A B D F
A B D G
A B E F
A B E G
```

No-one said answers have to be complete, they might just be helpful, or partial. Maybe you, or someone else, feels like adding the necessary *"massaging"*.

Comment: nice I love it +1

Comment: This works: `sed 'y/ []/,::/;s/:,//;s/^\([^:]*\),/"\1"/;s/:/ ::: /g;y/,/ /;s/[ :]*$//'   <<< 'A B [C,D,E] [F,G]' | xargs parallel -k echo :::`.

Comment: @agc Cool, put it as an answer for all to see and show off your `sed` skills. Or edit it into my answer if you wish. I don't see SO as a competition but more as a brilliant resource so I'm not worried about any points and the more good information there is on here, the better!

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Went with [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316772/6136214), (which took a few drafts to pare down).

Answer (score 2):

If you accept other solutions than `sed` you can use a one-liner `awk` solution:

```
echo A B [C,D,E] [F,G] | awk '{a=$1; b=$2; tmp1=$3; tmp2=$4}END{split(substr(tmp1,2,length(tmp1)-2),arr1,","); split(substr(tmp2,2,length(tmp2)-2),arr2,","); for(i in arr1){for(j in arr2){print a" "b" "arr1[i]" "arr2[j]" \\n"}}}'
```

**output:**

```
A B C F \n
A B C G \n
A B D F \n
A B D G \n
A B E F \n
A B E G \n
```

you can remove `" \\n"` if you do not need to display the `\n` at the end of each line

Answer (score 2):

Suppose *inputfile* contains:

```
A B [C,D,E] [F,G]
A B C [D,E] [M,N]
```

Use `sed` to parse those into a form that `parallel` likes, (method borrowed from [*Mark Setchell's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48316032/6136214)), one line at a time:

```
sed 's/ \[\|\] \[/ ::: /g;y/,]/  /;s/^/"/;s/ :/" :/;s/ $//' inputfile | 
xargs -L 1 parallel -k echo :::
```

Output:

```
A B C F
A B C G
A B D F
A B D G
A B E F
A B E G
A B C D M
A B C D N
A B C E M
A B C E N
```

Notes:

- The `sed` code is not optimal.
- A skim of the examples in `man parallel` suggests the possibility of replacing `xargs` with some additional `parallel` magic.